# Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/mimetypes.default

Tags: java, android, jar, gmail

I'm trying to send emails from my android app using Gmail libraries (mail.jar, activation.jar, additional.jar), but I face this error:

```
>Error:Execution failed for task 
>':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. > 
>com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
>com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in
> APK META-INF/mimetypes.default 
> File1: C:\Users\Deema-chan\Desktop\RPR Programming Tries\RPRok9\app\libs\activation.jar 
> File2: C:\Users\Deema-?chan\Desktop\RPR Programming Tries\RPRok9\app\libs\mail.jar
```

I read posts about the same problem but most of the solutions mentioned are adding these lines of code:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

but nothing changed and the same error remained. Any ideas of what to do?

Answer (score 0):

U can use this line in gradle.build

```
packagingOptions {
 pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ^^ But this still did not solve the problem